# "This branch has conflicts that must be resolved" but no option to resolve

Tags: git, github, merge-conflict-resolution, git-fork

I have only seen this question asked about pull requests, but I have not made a pull request. Normally if I have this issue with a PR, I go to the PR and it tells me exactly what files are creating the conflict and it gives me the option to resolve. But I just have a forked repo that I'm trying to update because the origin changed. I go to 'sync fork' and it only gives me the option to discard my commits. I want to see exactly what files are causing the conflicts and resolve them. How do I resolve conflicts in a repo without having made a pull request?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pull request from the main repo to your fork (just create a new pull request, click on "Compare across forks" and select the branches you want).